# Python Koans multiplayer Greed Game

Tags: python, performance, python-2.x, random, dice

I finished the [Python Koans](https://github.com/gregmalcolm/python_koans) because I wanted to practise Python and I completed the extra assignment which is the [Greed Game](https://github.com/gregmalcolm/python_koans/blob/master/python2/koans/about_extra_credit.py) (see the rules [here](https://github.com/gregmalcolm/python_koans/blob/master/python2/koans/GREEDS_RULES.txt)).

I think there are no flaws but you never know.

```
import random

class DiceSet(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._values = None

    @property
    def values(self):
        return self._values

    def roll(self, n):
        self._values = []
        for i in range(0, n):
            val = random.randint(1, 6)
            self._values.append(val)
        return self._values

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, name=""):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        if self.name:
            return "'{0}'".format(self.name)
        else:
            return "'Anonymous player'"

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()


class Game(object):
    def __init__(self, players, dice, goal = 3000):
        if len(players) < 2:
            raise "This game is for 2 or more players."
        self.dice = dice
        self.players_scores = dict((player, 0) for player in players)
        self.number_of_players = len(self.players_scores)
        self.players = [player for player in self.players_scores.keys()]
        self.turn = random.randint(0, len(self.players)-1)
        self.goal = goal

    def play(self):
        final_round = False
        first_player_to_reach_firnal_round = None

        while not final_round:
            self._print_turn()
            won_score = self._turn_score()
            self.players_scores[self.players[self.turn]] += won_score
            print "{0} has won {1} points (total {2}).".format(self.players[self.turn], won_score, self.players_scores[self.players[self.turn]])
            if self.players_scores[self.players[self.turn]] >= self.goal:
                final_round = True
                first_player_to_reach_firnal_round = self.turn
                print "{0} has reached over {1} points. Next round will be the last round.".format(self.players[self.turn], self.goal)
            self.turn = (self.turn + 1) % self.number_of_players

        # Last round. The player that reached the goal number of points doesn't play this round.
        print "\n\nLAST ROUND!!! Let's see who wins!"
        while self.turn != first_player_to_reach_firnal_round:
            self._print_turn()
            won_score = self._turn_score()
            self.players_scores[self.players[self.turn]] += won_score
            print "{0} has won {1} points (total {2}).".format(self.players[self.turn], won_score, self.players_scores[self.players[self.turn]])
            self.turn = (self.turn + 1) % self.number_of_players

        winner = self._winner()
        print "\n\nCongratulations, {0}! You have won the Greed Game!".format(winner)

    def score(self, dice):
        result = 0
        if len(dice) <= 5:
            dice_dict = dict((i, dice.count(i)) for i in dice)
            if dice_dict.get(1) >= 3:
                result += 1000
                dice_dict[1] -= 3
            for number in dice_dict:
                if dice_dict.get(number) >= 3:
                    result += number * 100
                    dice_dict[number] -= 3
            if 1 in dice_dict:
                result += dice_dict[1] * 100
                dice_dict[1] = 0
            if 5 in dice_dict:
                result += dice_dict[5] * 50
                dice_dict[5] = 0

        non_scoring_dice = [die for die in dice_dict.keys() if dice_dict[die] != 0]
        return result, non_scoring_dice

    def _turn_score(self):
        total_score = 0
        keep_rolling = False

        dice = self.dice.roll(5)
        print "\n{0} rolls the dice and gets {1}.".format(self.players[self.turn], dice)
        rolling_score, dice = self.score(dice)

        if rolling_score > 0:
            # If dice is empty it means there were no non-scoring dice after the roll, so the player gets the choice to roll all 5 dice again
            number_of_rollable_dice = 5 if not dice else len(dice)
            numbers = { 1: "one", 2: "two", 3: "three", 4: "four", 5: "five" }
            print "That's a score of {0} points and {1} non-scoring {2} can be rolled again.".format(rolling_score, number_of_rollable_dice, "die" if number_of_rollable_dice == 1 else "dice")

            total_score += rolling_score

            player_choice = raw_input("\n{0}, will you roll again? (y/n): ".format(self.players[self.turn]))
            if player_choice.upper() in ["Y", "YES"]:
                keep_rolling = True

            while keep_rolling:
                dice = self.dice.roll(number_of_rollable_dice)
                print "\n{0} rolls the dice and gets {1}.".format(self.players[self.turn], dice)
                rolling_score, dice = self.score(dice)

                if rolling_score > 0:
                    number_of_rollable_dice = 5 if not dice else len(dice)
                    numbers = { 1: "one", 2: "two", 3: "three", 4: "four", 5: "five" }
                    print "That's a score of {0} points and {1} non-scoring {2} can be rolled again.".format(rolling_score, number_of_rollable_dice, "die" if number_of_rollable_dice == 1 else "dice")

                    if total_score + rolling_score >= 300:
                        total_score += rolling_score
                        print "Since you reached more than 300 points this turn, your turn score is now {0}".format(total_score)
                    else:
                        total_score = rolling_score
                        print "Your turn score is less than 300 points, so now it's just the rolling score, {0} points.".format(total_score)

                    player_choice = raw_input("\n{0}, will you roll again? (y/n): ".format(self.players[self.turn]))
                    if player_choice.upper() in ["Y", "YES"]:
                        keep_rolling = True
                    else:
                        keep_rolling = False
                else:
                    print "That's a zero-point roll, you lost your turn and all your won points in this turn."
                    keep_rolling = False
                    total_score = 0
        else:
            print "That's a zero-point roll, you cannot roll again in this turn."

        return total_score

    def _winner(self):
        return max(self.players_scores, key = self.players_scores.get)

    def _print_turn(self):
        print "\n------------------------------------------\nStarting turn of {0} [Score: {1}]\n".format(self.players[self.turn], self.players_scores[self.players[self.turn]])

    def _print_scores(self):
        print "\n------------------------------------------\nScores table\n"
        for player, score in self.players_scores:
            print "{0}: {1} points".format(player, score)

player1 = Player("Player 1")
player2 = Player("Player 2")
players = [ player1, player2 ]
dice = DiceSet()
game = Game(players, dice, 1500)
game.play()
```

I am looking for comments and answers in these points:

- Is the class hierarchy acceptable?
- Are the methods in the correct classes?
- Should I have arranged the logic differently?
- Comments and tips on my code.
- Suggestions of Python-style ways of doing this
- Improvement and optimizations of my code
- Ideas of how to implement this in more interesting, original or interesting ways

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**About `DiceSet`**

It seems like the `values` property is never used. Let's get rid of it for the time being. Now, what do we have ? A class with 2 methods one of which is an `__init__`. I suggest you have a look at [this talk called "Stop Writing Classes "](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0). You can easily write this as a simple function :

```
def roll(n):
    values = []
    for i in range(0, n):
        val = random.randint(1, 6)
        values.append(val)
    return values
```

It makes everything much simpler. In particular, you don't need to create an instance of `DiceSet` and you don't need to keep it in your Game object. So much win.

More details :

- you don't need a `val` variable.
- you don't need the 0 as a first parameter to `range`.
- it is the convention to name `_` throw-away values.
- this looks like a situation where you could use a list comprehension.

Your whole `DiceSet` class is now down to this method :

```
def roll(n):
    return [random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(n)]
```

**About `score`**

The score method doesn't seem to access `self` at all. You could make this a classmethod or a simple independant function.

**About `play`**

There is a lot of duplicated code here. You can remove a lot out of it by thinking about what the ending condition for the game is : it is when we go back to the first player who has reached the final round (if any). You can simply write this :

```
def play(self):
    first_player_to_reach_final_round = None

    while self.turn != first_player_to_reach_final_round:
        self._print_turn()
        won_score = self._turn_score()
        self.players_scores[self.players[self.turn]] += won_score
        print "{0} has won {1} points (total {2}).".format(self.players[self.turn], won_score, self.players_scores[self.players[self.turn]])
        if self.players_scores[self.players[self.turn]] >= self.goal:
            if first_player_to_reach_final_round is None:
                first_player_to_reach_final_round = self.turn
            print "{0} has reached over {1} points. Next round will be the last round.".format(self.players[self.turn], self.goal)
            print "\n\nLAST ROUND!!! Let's see who wins!"
        self.turn = (self.turn + 1) % self.number_of_players

    winner = self._winner()
    print "\n\nCongratulations, {0}! You have won the Greed Game!".format(winner)
```

**About `self.turn`**

As far as I can tell, `self.turn` is interesting only in the `play` method. You can propagage the relevant information (name and/or score) to the other method needing it.

By doing this, you can again make things a lot simpler by just having a `turn` variable in `play`.

**Extracting user interaction in separated functions**

It might be a good idea to extract the user interactions in separated functions. It makes input checking easier and make the game logic clearer.

Here's what I have written :

```
def ask_yes_no_question(prompt):
    user_input = raw_input(prompt)
    return user_input.upper() in ["Y", "YES"]

def ask_roll_again(player):
    return ask_yes_no_question("\n{0}, will you roll again? (y/n): ".format(player))
```

It's simple and clear.

**About `turn_score`**

There is still quite a lot going on here. The logic `number_of_rollable_dice = 5 if not dice else len(dice)` is duplicated looks like maybe it shoud be part of the `score` function (telling how many dice are left to play). Also, it could be a good idea to have a constant containg 5 to make things less confusing.

At this point, the code looks like :

```
import random

DEFAULT_DICE_NUMBER = 5

def roll(n):
    return [random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(n)]

def score(dice):
    result = 0
    if len(dice) <= 5:
        dice_dict = dict((i, dice.count(i)) for i in dice)
        if dice_dict.get(1) >= 3:
            result += 1000
            dice_dict[1] -= 3
        for number in dice_dict:
            if dice_dict.get(number) >= 3:
                result += number * 100
                dice_dict[number] -= 3
        if 1 in dice_dict:
            result += dice_dict[1] * 100
            dice_dict[1] = 0
        if 5 in dice_dict:
            result += dice_dict[5] * 50
            dice_dict[5] = 0

    remaining_dice = len([die for die in dice_dict.keys() if dice_dict[die] != 0])
    remaining_dice = remaining_dice if remaining_dice else DEFAULT_DICE_NUMBER
    return result, remaining_dice


def print_turn(player, score):
    print "\n------------------------------------------\nStarting turn of {0} [Score: {1}]\n".format(player, score)


def ask_yes_no_question(prompt):
    user_input = raw_input(prompt)
    return user_input.upper() in ["Y", "YES"]

def ask_roll_again(player):
    return ask_yes_no_question("\n{0}, will you roll again? (y/n): ".format(player))


class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, name=""):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        if self.name:
            return "'{0}'".format(self.name)
        else:
            return "'Anonymous player'"

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()


class Game(object):
    def __init__(self, players, goal = 3000):
        if len(players) < 2:
            raise "This game is for 2 or more players."
        self.players_scores = dict((player, 0) for player in players)
        self.number_of_players = len(self.players_scores)
        self.players = [player for player in self.players_scores.keys()]
        self.goal = goal

    def play(self):
        first_player_to_reach_final_round = None
        turn = random.randint(0, len(self.players)-1)

        while turn != first_player_to_reach_final_round:
            player = self.players[turn]
            score = self.players_scores[player]
            print_turn(player, score)
            won_score = self._turn_score(player)
            self.players_scores[player] += won_score
            print "{0} has won {1} points (total {2}).".format(player, won_score, self.players_scores[player])
            if self.players_scores[player] >= self.goal:
                if first_player_to_reach_final_round is None:
                    first_player_to_reach_final_round = turn
                print "{0} has reached over {1} points. Next round will be the last round.".format(player, self.goal)
                print "\n\nLAST ROUND!!! Let's see who wins!"
            turn = (turn + 1) % self.number_of_players

        winner = self._winner()
        print "\n\nCongratulations, {0}! You have won the Greed Game!".format(winner)

    def _turn_score(self, player):
        total_score = 0
        keep_rolling = False

        dice = roll(DEFAULT_DICE_NUMBER)
        print "\n{0} rolls the dice and gets {1}.".format(player, dice)
        rolling_score, nb_dice = score(dice)

        if rolling_score > 0:
            # If dice is empty it means there were no non-scoring dice after the roll, so the player gets the choice to roll all 5 dice again
            numbers = { 1: "one", 2: "two", 3: "three", 4: "four", 5: "five" }
            print "That's a score of {0} points and {1} non-scoring {2} can be rolled again.".format(rolling_score, nb_dice, "die" if nb_dice == 1 else "dice")

            total_score += rolling_score

            keep_rolling = ask_roll_again(player) 

            while keep_rolling:
                dice = roll(nb_dice)
                print "\n{0} rolls the dice and gets {1}.".format(player, dice)
                rolling_score, nb_dice = score(dice)

                if rolling_score > 0:
                    numbers = { 1: "one", 2: "two", 3: "three", 4: "four", 5: "five" }
                    print "That's a score of {0} points and {1} non-scoring {2} can be rolled again.".format(rolling_score, nb_dice, "die" if nb_dice == 1 else "dice")

                    if total_score + rolling_score >= 300:
                        total_score += rolling_score
                        print "Since you reached more than 300 points this turn, your turn score is now {0}".format(total_score)
                    else:
                        total_score = rolling_score
                        print "Your turn score is less than 300 points, so now it's just the rolling score, {0} points.".format(total_score)

                    keep_rolling = ask_roll_again(player)
                else:
                    print "That's a zero-point roll, you lost your turn and all your won points in this turn."
                    keep_rolling = False
                    total_score = 0
        else:
            print "That's a zero-point roll, you cannot roll again in this turn."

        return total_score

    def _winner(self):
        return max(self.players_scores, key = self.players_scores.get)

    def _print_scores(self):
        print "\n------------------------------------------\nScores table\n"
        for player, score in self.players_scores:
            print "{0}: {1} points".format(player, score)

player1 = Player("Player 1")
player2 = Player("Player 2")
players = [ player1, player2 ]
game = Game(players, 1500)
game.play()
```

**About `turn_score` again**

There is still too much going on here. Also, many things seem to be happening in different places : rolling dices, printing, asking user if he wants to roll, etc.

You can rewrite the logic in a much concise and clearer way :

```
def _turn_score(self, player):
    total_score = 0
    nb_dice = DEFAULT_DICE_NUMBER

    while True:
        dice = roll(nb_dice)
        print "\n{0} rolls the dice and gets {1}.".format(player, dice)
        rolling_score, nb_dice = score(dice)
        if rolling_score == 0:
            if total_score:
                print "That's a zero-point roll, you lost your turn and all your won points in this turn."
            else:
                print "That's a zero-point roll, you cannot roll again in this turn."
            return 0
        else:
            print "That's a score of {0} points and {1} non-scoring {2} can be rolled again.".format(rolling_score, nb_dice, "die" if nb_dice == 1 else "dice")
            if total_score + rolling_score >= 300:
                total_score += rolling_score
                print "Since you reached more than 300 points this turn, your turn score is now {0}".format(total_score)
            else:
                total_score = rolling_score
                print "Your turn score is less than 300 points, so now it's just the rolling score, {0} points.".format(total_score)
            if not ask_roll_again(player):
                return total_score
```

**You don't need a class (again)**

At the end, the `Game` class is not needed anymore. Everything can happen from the `play` function.

It would go like this :

```
import random

DEFAULT_DICE_NUMBER = 5
NB_POINTS_TO_START = 300

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, name=""):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        if self.name:
            return "'{0}'".format(self.name)
        else:
            return "'Anonymous player'"

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()


def roll(n):
    return [random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(n)]


def score(dice):
    result = 0
    if len(dice) <= 5:
        dice_dict = dict((i, dice.count(i)) for i in dice)
        if dice_dict.get(1) >= 3:
            result += 1000
            dice_dict[1] -= 3
        for number in dice_dict:
            if dice_dict.get(number) >= 3:
                result += number * 100
                dice_dict[number] -= 3
        if 1 in dice_dict:
            result += dice_dict[1] * 100
            dice_dict[1] = 0
        if 5 in dice_dict:
            result += dice_dict[5] * 50
            dice_dict[5] = 0

    remaining_dice = len([die for die in dice_dict.keys() if dice_dict[die] != 0])
    remaining_dice = remaining_dice if remaining_dice else DEFAULT_DICE_NUMBER
    return result, remaining_dice


def print_turn(player, score):
    print "\n------------------------------------------\nStarting turn of {0} [Score: {1}]\n".format(player, score)


def ask_yes_no_question(prompt):
    user_input = raw_input(prompt)
    return user_input.upper() in ["Y", "YES"]


def ask_roll_again(player):
    return ask_yes_no_question("\n{0}, will you roll again? (y/n): ".format(player))


def turn_score(player):
    total_score = 0
    nb_dice = DEFAULT_DICE_NUMBER

    while True:
        dice = roll(nb_dice)
        print "\n{0} rolls the dice and gets {1}.".format(player, dice)
        rolling_score, nb_dice = score(dice)
        if rolling_score == 0:
            if total_score:
                print "That's a zero-point roll, you lost your turn and all your won points in this turn."
            else:
                print "That's a zero-point roll, you cannot roll again in this turn."
            return 0
        else:
            print "That's a score of {0} points and {1} non-scoring {2} can be rolled again.".format(rolling_score, nb_dice, "die" if nb_dice == 1 else "dice")
            if total_score + rolling_score >= NB_POINTS_TO_START:
                total_score += rolling_score
                print "Since you reached more than {0} points this turn, your turn score is now {1}".format(NB_POINTS_TO_START, total_score)
            else:
                total_score = rolling_score
                print "Your turn score is less than {0} points, so now it's just the rolling score, {1} points.".format(NB_POINTS_TO_START, total_score)
            if not ask_roll_again(player):
                return total_score


def get_winner(players_scores):
    return max(players_scores, key = players_scores.get)


def play_game(players, goal = 3000):
    if len(players) < 2:
        raise "This game is for 2 or more players."
    players_scores = dict((player, 0) for player in players)
    number_of_players = len(players_scores)
    players = [player for player in players_scores.keys()]

    first_player_to_reach_final_round = None
    turn = random.randint(0, len(players)-1)

    while turn != first_player_to_reach_final_round:
        player = players[turn]
        score = players_scores[player]
        print_turn(player, score)
        won_score = turn_score(player)
        players_scores[player] += won_score
        print "{0} has won {1} points (total {2}).".format(player, won_score, players_scores[player])
        if players_scores[player] >= goal:
            if first_player_to_reach_final_round is None:
                first_player_to_reach_final_round = turn
            print "{0} has reached over {1} points. Next round will be the last round.".format(player, goal)
            print "\n\nLAST ROUND!!! Let's see who wins!"
        turn = (turn + 1) % number_of_players

    winner = get_winner(players_scores)
    print "\n\nCongratulations, {0}! You have won the Greed Game!".format(winner)


player1 = Player("Player 1")
player2 = Player("Player 2")
play_game([player1, player2], 1500)
```

**More in `play_game`**

You don't need `len(players)`, you could just use `number_of_players`.

Assuming you are resetting the value of `players` to ensure we only consider **distinct** players, if would probably make sense to check the number of players after doing this.

Also, you could consider that it could be played alone too but this is up to you.

**A point of rule**

At the moment (I think it was the case before my changes), the part :

> Before a player is allowed to accumulate points, they must get at
>   least 300 points in a single turn. Once they have achieved 300 points
>   in a single turn, the points earned in that turn and each following
>   turn will be counted toward their total score.

I have the feeling that at the moment, one can start accumulating points even before 300.